# Mess in tags within a ListView (Android)

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I am trying to implement a fragment which holds a ListView bound to a custom adapter.
Basically, one row looks like this: TextViewName  ButtonPlus TextViewMarker ButtonMinus  ButtonRemove
The buttons plus and minus alter the number displayed by TextViewMarker. ButtonRemove removes a row from the list. Finally, there is a button to add new items in the list.
Everything seems to work fine since I can add and remove items and change the number of markers at runtime. Unfortunately, if I remove an item, the next item in the list takes the number of markers of the removed item. Just like if the ViewHolder was still at the same place and that the next item just changed his tag. I experience the same issue when the list is empty, if I add a new item, it will display the number of markers of the last item that was in the list...

Here is the code:

```
public class MarkerFragment extends Fragment
{
    private MarkerAdapter mAdapter = null;
    private EditText mAddItemEditText = null;
    private MainActivity mParent = null;

    public MarkerFragment(MainActivity parent){mParent = parent;}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_marker, null);

        Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddItem);
        b.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(this));

        mAddItemEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextItem);

        mAdapter = new MarkerAdapter(this, mParent);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.markerList);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void addItem(String name)
    {
        mAdapter.addItem(name);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position)
    {
        mAdapter.removeItem(position);
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name;
        TextView markers;
        int position = -1;
    }

    private class MarkerAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private MarkerFragment mParent;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ArrayList<String> mList;

        public MarkerAdapter(MarkerFragment parent, Context context)
        {
            super();

            this.mParent = parent;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            mList = new ArrayList<String>();
            mList.add("item1");
            mList.add("item2");
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRowName);
                holder.markers = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMarker);

                holder.markers.setText("0");

                Button b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus1Marker);
                b.setRotation(180);
                b.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(this.mParent));

                b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus1Marker);
                b.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(this.mParent));

                b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRemoveMarker);
                b.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(this.mParent));

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText(mList.get(position));
            holder.position = position;

            return convertView;
        }

        public void addItem(String name)
        {
            mList.add(name);
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeItem(int position)
        {
            mList.remove(position);
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return mList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
    }

    private class ClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {
        private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        private MarkerFragment mParent = null;

        public ClickListener(MarkerFragment parent)
        {
            mParent = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.buttonAddItem:
                addItem();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonMinus1Marker:
                alterMarkerNumber(v, -1);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonPlus1Marker:
                alterMarkerNumber(v, 1);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRemoveMarker:
                removeItem(v);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        private void alterMarkerNumber(View v, int point)
        {
            View row = (View) v.getParent();
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            int markers = Integer.parseInt(holder.markers.getText().toString()) + point;
            sb.delete(0, sb.capacity()).append(markers);
            holder.markers.setText(sb.toString());
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void addItem()
        {
            String name = mAddCardEditText.getText().toString();
            if(name.length() > 0)
            {
                name = name.replace("'", " ").replace("\"", " ");
                mAddItemEditText.setText("");
                this.mParent.addItem(name);
            }
        }

        private void removeItem(View v)
        {
            View row = (View) v.getParent();
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            if(holder.position != -1)
            {
                this.mParent.removeItem(holder.position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of removing ArrayList element by position, remove that by object(string) as u wl easily get which string to remove... holder.position is bit messy i think...

Comment: Already tried and it did not work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By implementing the ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter, the problem vanished.